# Can google pay be integrated as an external payment method?

Tags: php, ccavenue, google-pay

I am currently using CCavenue as my payment gateway, and we collect payments via email, where the Pay button is pre-configured with the URL, which redirects to the payment gateway. I am keen on using Google pay. Below are my few queries - 
a) Can a payment gateway be completely replaced by Google pay?
b) Can I embed google pay into the mail and receive the payment or it needs to be in-app only?

I am using Laravel as Backend.

Answer (score 3):

Google Pay does not process payments, and as such, works in combination with existing payment processors / gateways. [Here](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/#participating-google-pay-processors) is a list of supported processors as of today (CCAvenue does not seem to be in that list yet).

You can only use Google Pay wherever you can run JavaScript on the web (or on Android using Java or Kotlin), thus most email clients and services will not support such an integration.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried to embed the link into an email, which redirects to a page in my application where I am running the javascript, and the G-pay button showed up, I am wondering, whether I can proceed further using the same logic?

Comment: Sure thing, that works. It's as good as it gets if you want to start from an e-mail. You always need to end up in a place where you can run JavaScript securely.